# What is the best practice of styling GWT widgets?

Tags: java, gwt, widget

As question says, how to style user widgets? Some of them are stylized in theirs xml file, but default widgets have minimal css, and require external rules to style. However, it have some disadvantages, like hard changing styling of internal widgets of other. I'm not pretty sure what is the correct and pro solution of it. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/style.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO You are best off using current best practice for styling in pure JavaScript/CSS world. CSS has got very powerful so I'm not sure the clever stuff in GWT is generally worth learning. Also we generally outsource creating the gfx/CSS so it is easier to provide a set of graphics and CSS to be sent to us as standard/normal files.

There are great and powerful things in the GWT toolkit for styling but I'm not sure, for most cases, they are worth it.